# Is it possible to parse the sourcecode of this webpage?

Tags: html-parsing

I'm trying to make a program that fetches information from this webpage, [www.sio.no](http://www.sio.no/) , but when I try to view the sourcecode from my web-browser I only see some javascript commands.

Is there a way around this so I can access the text on the webpage?

Comment: I am able to see text when I open source code of few pages. Please provide page URL where you are not able to see source text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely possible, the "head" does have a lot of "script" tags in it, but if you scroll to the bottom you should see some html spaced by bazillions of newlines.

You should be able to parse the html from this page without problems. I used firefox to check that.